# jquery ajax calls conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my site i am loading shopping products with the "add to cart"-button dynamically with a jquery ajax call. For the shopping cart itself, I use jcart, jquery plugin.

When I then add an item to the cart, jcart calls a php-file with ajax and POST. All works fine, the products are correctly added to the cart, but the page reloads every time I add an item to the cart. 
When I don't use the ajax call to load the products (e.g. load them directly in the page), all works fine, so there must be a conflict somewhere.
Any clues?

This is my products-function and the html.

```
...
<script>
      function loadProducts(str) {
             $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   async: true,
                   url: 'ajax/load.php',
                   data: {'max-id' : str},
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(response) {
                        $('#products').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                   },
                 });
        }
</script>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var n = '';
       loadProducts(n);
     });
</script>

<script src="jcart/js/jcart.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The jcart-Plugin with its ajax-call can befound here:
http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/standalone-demo/jcart/js/jcart.js

Here are the functions from jcart.js.

```
            $.ajaxSetup({
            type: 'POST',
            url: path + '/relay.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                // Refresh the cart display after a successful Ajax request
                container.html(response);
                $('#jcart-buttons').remove();
            },
            error: function(x, e) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

...

```
    function add(form) {
        // Input values for use in Ajax post
        var itemQty = form.find('[name=' + config.item.qty + ']'),
            itemAdd = form.find('[name=' + config.item.add + ']');

        // Add the item and refresh cart display
        $.ajax({
            data: form.serialize() + '&' + config.item.add + '=' + itemAdd.val(),
            success: function(response) {

                // Momentarily display tooltip over the add-to-cart button
                if (itemQty.val() > 0 && tip.css('display') === 'none') {
                    tip.fadeIn('100').delay('400').fadeOut('100');
                }

                container.html(response);
                $('#jcart-buttons').remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

...

```
    // Add an item to the cart
            // is called from the submit-buttons within each product picture
    $('.jcart').submit(function(e) {
        add($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The "loadProducts()" function puts this into #products container for each item:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="SDK12345" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="Product Name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-price" value="1.00" />
        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" />
        <ul>
            <li><img src="product-image.jpg"/></li>
            <li>1.00 Dollar</li>
            </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Where's the ajax code that uses POST?

Comment: It's in the jcart.js file, you can find it here as mentioned above: http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/standalone-demo/jcart/js/jcart.js

Comment: The ajax call in your add() function lacks an url.

Comment: The url is defined in the ajaxSetup and works fine.
I only have problems with the loadProducts() AND "add-to-cart" together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

As the forms are loaded via ajax, they were no correctly interpreted by jcart.js (though the functions all worked fine for themselves).

"bind" didn't work, but "live" fixed it:

```
$('.jcart').live('submit',function(e) {
  add($(this));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are calling the loadProducts() function in a binded click action on your add to cart button. If you are using an element with a default click behavior. You might want to prevent that with a 'return false;' on the last line of your binded click function.

like this:

```
$('a.addtocart').bind('click', function(){
  //logic here (ajax)
  return false;
});
```

After your success function there's also a comma that might get messy in IE:

```
success: function(response) {
  $('#products').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
},
```

Remove the comma

I think there's an error in your ajax call, try to work it out... i cant see the logic of your php file that adds products to your basket. but if you want to send the data of your form (quantity, itemid), serializing your form data should be enough. No need to pass extra get variables.

```
     function add(form) {
        $.ajax({
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            url: 'yourfile.php',
            success: function(response) {

                // logic
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: Hi feskr, thanks for the hint. The comma is gone.
The "add to cart"-function is called by clicking a submit-button within each product. The "loadProducts()" is called immediatly when the page is loaded ($(document).ready(function()). I already tried "return false" and "e.preventDefault()", but nothing worked. The e.preventDefault was in the jcart srcipt from the beginning.

Comment: do you use the submit button in a form? if so, you can try to add an attribute to your form tag: onsubmit="return false;" //ow you added some info :)

Comment: I tried the onsubmit="return false;" on the form. The page is now not reloaded, but the cart update doesn't work either then.

Comment: Thanks. The php logic works fine, also the complete jcart.js works fine - just until i load the products with the forms dinamically.
The data already gets serialized in function add(form), with
"data: form.serialize() + '&' + config.item.add + '=' + itemAdd.val(),"